# Could you please clarify the meanings of "School"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I am a bit confused about the meanings of "**School**". I included my thoughts in parentheses and in bold.

Ok, in [dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/school_1?q=school),

School could be

> - [countable] a place where children go to be educated.
>
>   Ex: *There are a school & a church in that village.* (**I think this is
>     a physical school**).
> - [uncountable] (used without the or a) the process of learning in a
>     school; the time during your life when you go to a school (British
>     English)
>
>   Ex: *to start/leave school*
>
>   (North American English) *to start/quit school*
>
>   (British English) *All my kids are still at school.* (**I would think this
>     sentence means the kids are still at the age of schooling & have not
>     graduated high-school yet**)
>
>   (North American English) *All my kids are still in school.*
> - [uncountable] (used without the or a) the time during the day when
>     children are working in a school
>
>   Ex: *Shall I meet you after school today?*
>
>   *The kids are at/in school until 3.30.* (**I would think this sentence
>     means the kids are studying at school at this moment & have not gone
>     home yet**)
> - [countable, uncountable] (North American English, informal) a college
>     or university; the time that you spend there
>
>   Ex: (as a countable noun) *There are 5 schools in my city* (**I think they are 5 physical colleges or universities**)
>
>   (as an uncountable noun) All my kids are still in school. (**I would
>     think this sentence means the kids are still at the process of
>     learning in their higher-education & have not graduated higher
>     education programs yet**)

I am not sure my thinking is right or not. But that is what I understand the meanings of "**School**" from the dictionary.

Could you please clarify the meanings of "**School**"?

Comment: I do not understand what you want "clarified". You tell us you are aware *school* can represent different things, and you have found those meanings in a dictionary so if you do not tell us precisely what meaning of school you do not understand in the definitions you found in the dictionary, I do not see how we can help you.

Comment: I am not sure my thinking is right or not! I am not a native

Comment: @Tom So is it what you think or what the dictionary tells you?

Comment: Tom, as far as I can tell, you have the right idea for all of them.